# Enabling SSL on Squid

Tags: security, ssl, openssl, squid

I installed Squid server and I am trying to secure it. 
In many searches, I see that is possible to enable SSL for squid.
Is there any security benefits for squid server to enable SSL on it?

Answer (score 0):

Proxy and ssl don't walk together. If you wish to filter ssl traffic you must practically do man-in-the-middle attack. Communication will go `pc` -> `ssl1` -> `proxy` -> `ssl2` -> `https_site`.

Where is `ssl1` fake ssl between pc and proxy. in this case `ssl2` is true ssl with valid certificates.

In this traffic flow you have unencrypted packets on proxy server and can be read.
This is unsecure.

Also check legal regulation because do proxy on ebanking is crime.